# When booting from Kali Linux USB drive I get logged in as root without a passward

Tags: linux, kali-linux

When booting from Kali Linux USB drive I get logged in as root without a password. I don't see any log in screen to enter password but get logged in directly. Instead if I logout or lock my PC then I get get login screen.
Any idea why this is happening and how can I make Kali linux ask for password while booting?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Most Linux live sessions work the same way. Changing it implies modifying the ISO.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia That's unfortunate to hear. As not requiring a password raises many security concerns. By the way Thanks for clarifying. At least now I can have good sleep knowing that there is no problem with my USB live and I don't have to do it again.

Comment: A live session isn't intended for daily usage or to have personal data. It's intended for installing and, in the case of Kali is to be used as is, to run penetration testing software. In neither case there's nothing personal there so what would be the security concerns? Someone using Kali for its intended purpose should know that and a lot more really.

Answer (score 0):

For the version of kali after enabling persistence on USB live below configuration worked for me and is static after reboot.

```
$ uname -a;grep autologin-user /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
Linux kali 5.15.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.15-2kali1 (2022-01-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# autologin-user = User to log in with by default (overrides autologin-guest)
# autologin-user-timeout = Number of seconds to wait before loading default user
#autologin-user=kali
autologin-user-timeout=0
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo passwd kali
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).